# Overclock Antminer U3 running on raspberry pi

Tags: mining-hardware, bfgminer, antminer, raspberry-pi, u3

I have an Antminer u3 running on a raspberry pi using bfgminer. Its currently running at 47GH/s. Does anyone know if  is possible to over clock it using BGFminer so that it will run at 55 - 60 GH/s?

if i cant do it using BFGminer is there another mining software i can do it in?

any suggestions would be welcome and would be appreciated:)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I set up my rasp pi b+ and U3 mining rig using the [instructions in this forum post](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=103046&p=727350), with screen and cgminer.

The command relevant to over clocking the raspi that I used is the following:

```
sudo ./cgminer --bmsc-options 115200:0.57 -o POOL -u USERNAME -p PASSWORD --bmsc-voltage 0800 --bmsc-freq 1286
```

Those last two options (bmsc-voltage and bmsc-freq) are what over clocked the rasp pi.  But I think I had to compile cgminer and configure it to include bmsc.  Mine typically runs with a hash rate in the high 50's or low 60's, but maybe not quite 62-63 GH/s.

Also, I did try to push the U3 voltage and frequency higher by playing with the settings as [detailed in the U3 manual](https://www.bitmaintech.com/files/download/AntMiner-U3%20user%20guide.pdf).  However, I could never get the U3 to run stably at settings any higher than what I gave above.  I'm not sure if it makes a difference, but I'm actually running two U3's on the one rasp pi and cgminer instance.

Update: In the interest of providing a complete answer in one place, here's the full text from the linked forum post:

> Run a fresh install of Raspbian using NOOBS, after the install type `ifconfig` and make a note of the IP address, so that you can remotely
>   SSH into your Pi. Login via PuTTY with the default username/password,
>   then raspi-config if you would like to change the hostname, default
>   password and so on.
>
> Now update the Pi: 
>   `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`
>
> Install dependencies:
>
> `sudo apt-get install libusb-1.0-0-dev libusb-1.0-0 libcurl4-openssl-dev libncurses5-dev libudev-dev screen libtool automake pkg-config libjansson-dev screen`
>
> Clone cgminer from here: 
>   `git clone https://github.com/bitmaintech/cgminer`
>
> Install, configure and also enable bmsc options:
>
> `cd cgminer`
>
> `sudo ./autogen.sh`
>
> `export LIBCURL_CFLAGS=’-I/usr/include/curl’`
>
> `sudo ./configure --enable-bmsc`
>
> `sudo make`
>
> Test cgminer is working correctly by running the following (input your
>   own pool, username and password):
>
> `sudo ./cgminer --bmsc-options 115200:0.57 -o POOL -u USERNAME -p PASSWORD --bmsc-voltage 0800 --bmsc-freq 1286`
>
> Type Q to exit cgminer...
>
> Now, add cgminer to start automatically when the Pi is powered on and
>   create a screen session:
>
> `sudo nano /etc/rc.local`
>
> Remember, Ctrl-X to exit, then type Y and press Enter to save changes. Add this just above
>   exit 0, again enter your own pool, username and password:
>
> `cd /home/pi/cgminer`
>
> `screen -dmS cgminer ./cgminer --bmsc-options 115200:0.57 -o POOL -u USERNAME -p PASSWORD --bmsc-voltage 0800 --bmsc-freq 1286`

Comment: Thankyou, its now running at around 58gh/s :D

Comment: no problem, glad I could help!

Answer (score 2):

I have 2 u3 antminers running on a raspberry pi b+ 
I could not get my u3 any faster until i used minera software,set to cgminer (offical)
with command: `--au3-volt 830  --au3-freq 250.0`    In the settings menu
 it will run at 62-63 GH/s.
you can download it hear  http://getminera.com/